# Overriding CSS styles in Material UI Stepper with CSS API

Tags: javascript, css, material-design, material-ui, uistepper

I would like to change text color (which is actually a SVG Icon) in Material UI StepIcon only for active and completed steps. At the moment, I successfully changed color of an icon for those steps. That's how my *MuiTheme* looks like now.

```
export default createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiStepIcon: {
      root: {
        '&$active': {
          color: styles.myGreen,
        },
        '&$completed': {
          color: styles.myGreen,
        },
      },
    }
  },
});
```

And whole stepper looks like:

[image: Steppers with applied colors]

Assumings, I would like to change color of *tick* to gray (which represents completed steps) and color of *number two* to gray as well (which represents currently active step), while keeping *inactive step* not changed (white fill).

Changing fill property for text like in [official documentation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/StepIcon/StepIcon.js) does not give any results, in developer inspector still shows fill equal white.

I want to apply that styling for whole app.

Any tips or solution for this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to override the text class too

```
export default createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiStepIcon: {
      root: {
        '&$active': {
          color: styles.myGreen,
        },
        '&$completed': {
          color: styles.myGreen,
        },
      },
      text: {
        fill: <YOUR_DESIRED_COLOR>
      },
     },
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert this into CSS from js?